# Problema para ordenar tabla relacionada laravel

Tags: laravel, eloquent

Estoy intentando ordenar una tabla relacionada sin éxito el controlador original es así:

```
$products = Product::orderBy('nombre', 'asc')
      ->where('user_id', auth()->user()->id)->with('Coment')
      ->get();
```

Y la forma que estoy intentando es así:

```
$products = Product::orderBy('nombre', 'asc')
          ->where('user_id', auth()->user()->id)->with(['coment' => function ($query) {
    $query->orderBy('created_at', 'desc');
}])->get();
```

pero no consigo que se ordene.. donde puede estar el error ?

Comment: intentas ordenar por el nombre de manera desc y también por el created_at de manera desc?

Comment: Lo que quiero es la tabla product por nombre asc y la tabla coment por created_at desc

Comment: No me queda claro, ¿quieres ordenar la tabla o los resultados de la consulta? son dos cosas muy distintas.

Comment: El resultado de la consulta